# Don't understand question: correlation w.r.t.

Tags: terminology

This is related to pattern recognition, specifically augmented neural networks. I do not understand what a correlation "w.r.t." is, or what it stands for. Anyone?

Here is the question in full:

> Vary the learning rate, the number of hidden layer nodes, and the
>   number of training/test data. And then, find the correlation **w.r.t.**
>   the recognition rate.

Comment: with respect to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"w.r.t." generally means "with respect to."

Comment: Ah it was so simple, thank you!